# Triggering a new version of App Engine application from changes committed to GitHub

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to create a new version of my Python App Engine project in Google Cloud and connect this new version to a GitHub repository so it can retrieve the source code from there.

In addition, I want to update the source code whenever I commit anything in GitHub. Any idea on how to create a new version in App Engine and connect it to GitHub repo?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Cloud Build. Here's the [quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories).

Note that the guide is based on using Cloud Source Repository, but you have the option to select GitHub as your trigger source.